# Homogeneous Markov Chain with Continuous time

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, continuity

Can a transition matrix in a homogeneous Markov chain with continuous time turn out to be discontinuous in t?

Comment: What do you mean by discontinuity of a Markov chain/transition matrix?

Comment: @saz Markov chain in homogeneous if $P(t_1, t_2)$ depends on only $t_2-t_1$. Thus we get semigroup {P(t) | t in [0,inf)} by virtue of P(t1+t2) = P(t1)P(t2), P(0) = I where I = (δij)i,j=1,...,r. where δij is equal to 1 when i = j  and 0 otherwise. So, could this mapping P be disctontinuous? or continuous, but not differentiable? With examples, if yes.

Comment: @saz, have you understood me?

Comment: No, I haven't but perhaps somebody else will

Comment: You asked the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580738/homogeneous-markov-chain-continuous-but-not-differentiable